# Grid throwing out element out of screen

Tags: html, css

I have two **filedsets** in a page. The grid-container is inside second **fieldset**.

I am using **display:grid** for two * clild divs* in larger screen. And in small screen there will be no grid. So I want both the * clild divs* to be one after another(up and down).

But In small screen the whole **second filedset** is getting out of screen. Or maybe the first fieldset is not covering 100% width.

I do not know which is causing the problem and also do not know how to solve it. Can anyone please help?

**If from full page result you start reducing browser width, you will find out the problem.**
[Full page result](https://cdpn.io/mehdi-aziz-rafi/debug/oNWYjze/YvMgOwvaQLQM)

[Full Code in Codepen](https://codepen.io/mehdi-aziz-rafi/pen/oNWYjze)

```
fieldset{
    max-width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-color: red;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    border-radius:25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    perspective: 1px;

    margin:20px
}
@media (max-width:650px){
    .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
}
```

Comment: your html code please full from top to bottom if possible

Comment: link of that codepen  or your full html

Comment: sir can you provide me the source code link this is the website view link

Comment: @jashandeepsingh my mistake sorry here is the code [code](https://codepen.io/mehdi-aziz-rafi/pen/oNWYjze)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sir here is the final ans
here is the preview
[image]

sir you are facing this problem because you added to large size of font

chagne it to 50px or any other but smaller

```
  .grid-child-one div{
      border:7px solid white;
      padding: 30px;
      font-family:Garamond, serif;
    font-style: oblique;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
```

i used 30px it worked fine

Comment: you can also use the media query to change the font size i hope this will help you please reply if it worked

Comment: Brother, it completely worked. You save my day. See a Singh, salute a Singh.

Answer (score 0):

the information you shared is not much to guess what's the problem,
but still @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) ---- use this media query instead of @media (max-width:650px), it might solve your problem.

Comment: you mean that the form doesn't remain at the center when we reduce the width of the browser

Comment: If you keep reducing the width you will find out the problem

Answer (score 0):

sir here is your ans

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px){
    .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
}
}
```

try with grid at place of inline-grid
i hope it will work fine

here is full cope paste and try it

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  </head>
  <body>

    <style>
      *{
        margin: 0;
          padding:0;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
          box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        body, html {
          height: 100%;
        
          color:white;
        font-family: Candara;
        background-color:black;
          box-sizing: border-box;
          
          }
        /*
        Garamond, serif
        Candara
        */
        
        
        
        header{
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
          }
        .sticky {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          width: 100%;
          z-index: 999999999;
        }
        
        .sticky + .content {
          padding-top: 102px;
        }
        a.company{
          text-decoration:none;
          color:white;
        }
        #company{
            vertical-align: center;
            display: inline-block;
            /* To horizontally center images and caption */
            text-align: center;
            width:7%;
          border:1px solid white;
            background-color:rgb(75,0,130);
          
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
          #company {
            min-width:25%;
          margin:10px;
        
          }
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
          #company {
            width:15%;
          margin:10px;
          }
        }
        #company #name{
          font-size:15px;
          font-weight:bold;
        }
          
        fieldset{
          max-width:960px;
          margin:0 auto;
          border-color: red;
        }
          
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
          border-radius:25px;
          overflow: hidden;
            perspective: 1px;
        
          margin:20px;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 650px){
          .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 100%;
        }
        }
        .grid-child-one{
        
        background-color:blue;
        text-align:center;
        padding:30px;
        }
        .grid-child-one div{
          border:7px solid white;
          padding: 30px;
          font-family:Garamond, serif;
        font-style: oblique;
        font-size:100px;
        font-weight:bold;
        }
        .grid-child-two{
          background-color:white;
          color:black;
          padding:30px;
          
        }
        input{
          width:100%;
          border-radius:25px;
          padding:10px;
          font-size:20px;
          overflow:auto;
          margin: 10px 0;
          
        }
        .grid-child-two form{
        
          
        }
        input[type=submit]{
          width:100%;
          border-radius:25px;
          padding:10px;
          margin:20px 0;
          background-color:black;
          color:white;
          font-weight:bold;
        }
        
        
        .separator {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          text-align: center;
        }
        
        .separator::before,
        .separator::after {
          content: '';
          flex: 1;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
        }
        
        .separator:not(:empty)::before {
          margin-right: .25em;
        }
        
        .separator:not(:empty)::after {
          margin-left: .25em;
        }
        .hidden-child{
          font-style: oblique;
        font-size:100px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:black;
        }
    </style>
      
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
<header>

<fieldset class="content">
<a class="company" href="index.php">
<div id="company">
 <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8pWEq0Ws2LvaUdaL54gjglSViYF4IVL70GFVIk18uryQ9S1tO5NKtFKKEaYHRFKDFz9E&usqp=CAU" width="100%"/>
 <div id="name">HELLO</div>
 </div>
 </a>
</fieldset>

</header>
</div>
<script>
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
</script>
<section>
<fieldset>
<div class="grid-container" style="background-color: red;">

    <div class="grid-child-one">
      <div>Help<br>
        Me!</div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-child-two">
    <form>
  <label for="fname">email:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
  <label for="pass">password:</label><br>
  <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass">
  <input type="submit" id="sub" name="sub" value="login">
</form>
no account?
<form action="create.php" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="create account" 
         name="Submit" id="frm1_submit" />
</form>
    </div>
  
</div>
    <div class="hidden-child">
      hello<br>
        friend!
    </div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if this doesn't work inform me but also this send the screenshot of the problem

Comment: sir, [it is the code from you](https://codepen.io/mehdi-aziz-rafi/full/GRmNoKL) please open it on browser, and inspect in smaller screen (eg galaxy fold, iphone se ect)

Comment: sir i will try to find its solution i founded the problem